# PHP - MySQL - Loading data from XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a really strange problem. I want to load the MySQL connection attributes from an XML file, but I got this error when I try to process the connection:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed (Error number: 2002)
```

And why this is strange? Because if I just write down the mysql_connect() statement myself, and not from the xml file, it works.

The XML file looks like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <data>
   <host>"localhost"</host>       
   <username>"root"</username>
   <password>"password"</password>
   <database>"account"</database>
 </data>
```

The PHP part:

```
function connection() {
   $file = 'access.xml';
   if(file_exists($file)) {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
      $host = $xml->host;
      $name = $xml->username;
      $password = $xml->password;
      $database = $xml->database;

      $connect = mysql_connect($host,$name,$password);
      //mysql_select_db($database) or die("Adatbázis csatlakozás sikertelen.");
      } else {
          print "XML betöltése sikertelen. - MySQL csatlakozás sikertelen."; // Error message in hungarian language
      }
}
```

I thought about maybe the charset causes the problem, but no, because I already set the PHP's charset to UTF-8, my SQL server's charset is UTF-8, too, and as you can see, the XML file uses UTF-8. So, I really don't know what's the problem.

Thanks for the help,

Tomco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a sneaking suspicion it's the quotes in your XML. Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <data>
   <host>localhost</host>       
   <username>root</username>
   <password>password</password>
   <database>account</database>
 </data>
```

Quotes are used in your code to identify strings... But the XML parser already knows that it's working with strings, so it will treat the quotes you gave it as *part of that text*. So instead of expanding to:

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','account','password');
```

You're actually expanding to:

```
$connect = mysql_connect('"localhost"', '"account"', '"password"');
```

And while PHP can't find a server called `"localhost"`, it shouldn't have problems finding one called `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes in your access.xml file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <data>
   <host>localhost</host>       
   <username>root</username>
   <password>password</password>
   <database>account</database>
 </data>
```

it will work now